# How to add comprehensive help pages to classes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, documentation

I am working on an object oriented application in Matlab and are wondering how I can add comprehensive help pages like Matlab's own functions and classes do have. I am especially interested on adding Latex to the help pages. As an example I added a picture of how my help pages look like and what I would like to look them like.[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242145/what-is-the-mathworks-way-to-generate-matlab-html-documentation).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However the responses to that question are not very promising for me, as it seems like for classes (and functions) you need to write the documention in extra files seperated from the code. This adds off course to the maintenance effort.

Comment: Yes, it is gonna get more tricky, but it seems to be the way to get any closer to a Matlab-like help than what you have already achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more reading of the Matlab help pages, there seems to be a a way to get a nice and searchable documentation:

1. Add the help as [marked up](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html) comments at top of your class files.
2. Publish these files and [turn off the options](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/specifying-output-preferences-for-publishing.html) "Evaluate code", "Catch error" and if you don't want to display your code and the end of the help page also turn off "Include code".
3. When your application is finished, [package it](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/app-creation.html).
4. Move all the published html files in a folder, like "html" or "doc".
5. Add the [required xml files](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-custom-documentation.html) to your html directory.
6. Optionally add [examples](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-custom-examples.html).
7. Use [builddocsearchdb](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builddocsearchdb.html) to make your costum help searchable from the built in Matlab help browser.